# Vectors and maps in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector `A [9 3 6 9 3 6]` each 2 elements represent the edge of a graph, I wan to create the adjacency matrix from this vector.

First i created the unique vector `A [3 6 9]` to know the size of my matrix

Second I create a matrix and fill it with 0

Third I will run a loop on A to know what edges are connected, my question is how can I tell C++ that the first element in A which is three actually represent element 0 in my matrix, same for 6 that it represent 1 and 9 is represented by 3, like this when I construct my adjacency matrix i know that 0 1 2 represent actually 3 6 9, I heard about using a map but didn t know how to construct it in my program because im new to C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are essentially trying to track *labels* for your vertices. If each vertex has a sequentially assigned number, you can scan new vertex labels and insert the corresponding sequential number in a map, like so:

```
std::map<int, std::size_t> labels;  // "int" is the label type; could be anything!

std::size_t store_vertex_label(int v)
{
  std::map<int, std::size_t>::const_iterator const it = labels.find(v);

  if (it != labels.end()) return it->second;

  const std::size_t new_number = labels.size();
  labels.insert(std::make_pair(v, new_number);
  return new_number;
}
```

Now as you process your input, you read one label token `v` at a time, send it to `store_vertex_label()`, and you get the corresponding sequential vertex index back.

Your adjacency matrix will be of size `labels.size()` squared.

Note that your label type doesn't have to be an integer, it could be anything (e.g. a string).

Comment: Sorry, it should be `it->second` -- fixed!

Comment: Yes, because it should also be `if (it !=`... OK, I need to get some sleep! Sorry for that.

Comment: I have one last question, if I want to keep the map that we ve created in this function to use it later on, is it possible? or i should created another function and put the output as label not as size_t ?

Comment: @mona: Well, yes, you'd keep the `labels` map in the relevant scope where you need it. You can pass it to the store function by reference if you like, or (gasp) even make it global if you have a very small program.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways:

1. You can do a linear search to find the index of an element in a vector
2. Your vector seems to be sorted, binary search would also be possible
3. you can create a map rather than vector, if your elements in vector are not sorted. Populate the map with key as the "values in your vector" Vs value as the index where you insert.

First is worst solution. Use 3rd in case if vector is not sorted. Use 2nd if you want to reduce the space complexity. 3rd would also be good if large size and hashmap used.